# create dynamic multi-dimenstional associative array using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, multidimensional-array

Below is my JS code :

```
        var checkedLength = $(ele).parent().parent().find('table').find(':checkbox:checked').length;

    if(checkedLength)
{
     $(ele).parent().parent().find('table').find(':checkbox:checked').each(function(i) {
        $(this).parent().removeClass().addClass('play');
        $(this).prop('checked',false);
        var agn = $(this).data('agn');
        var value = $(this).data('kid');

        checkedValues[agn] = {};
        // Make bar an array, if it's not defined yet
        checkedValues[agn]["bar"] = checkedValues[agn]["bar"] || [];
        checkedValues[agn]["bar"].push(value);
    });
            console.log(checkedValues);
}
```

From above code am getting output as :

```
   object {agnName => bar[0] = 6}
```

Desired O/P :

```
   object {agnName => bar[0] = 4,bar[1] = 5 , bar[2]=> 6}
```

Can anyone guide me how can achieve this array structure ??

Thanks.

Comment: javasript does not support associative array, so you can create json object instead

Answer (score 3):

You want an object, not an array:

```
checkedValues = {};
checkedValues.foo = {};
checkedValues.foo.bar = 'baz';  

// Another way:
checkedValues["keyname"] = "value";

// You can also use variables as keys
var agn = "foo";
checkedValues[agn] = "value";

// Just don't forget to init nested objects
var agn = "foo";
checkedValues[agn] = {};
checkedValues[agn]["bar"] = "value";

// If you need an array inside:
var agn = "foo";
checkedValues[agn] = {};
// Make bar an array, if it's not defined yet
checkedValues[agn]["bar"] = checkedValues[agn]["bar"] || [];
checkedValues[agn]["bar"].push("value");
```

Comment: But, its in $.each function, have to create this array dynamically by looping through the rows in which checkboxes are checked which will have the data attributes 'agn' and 'kid'. Using this agn and kid values in need to create the array structure as shown above..

Comment: See my update, you can use variables as keys with bracket notation

Comment: checkedValues[agn]["bar"] = "value"; will replace the previous values with new value in loop, it has to be like checkedValues[agn]["bar"][] = "value"; like how we do in PHP to push values... i short checkedValues[agn]["bar"] shoud be an array of values ...

Comment: So make `bar` an array. See charlietfl's answer, and my comment below it.

Comment: Have tried it, 90% done, but i have checked 3 checkboxes from 3 tr in table, then ['bar'] index should have 3 values but it giving the final tr checkbox value only. I suppose the values are overwritten...

         Object { agnName={
                   bar [6]
         }}

it should be : 

          Object { agnName={
                 bar [4,5,6]
          }}

Comment: Updated my question with code changes u guys suggested ... still not getting desired output...

Comment: @arul.k Did you declare checkedValues somewhere? You must. `var checkedValues = {}`.

Answer (score 3):

You have a test to see if `checkedValues[agn]` exists and you create it as an empty object if it doesn't. However you then immediately try to push to an array within that object that doesn't exist

Try changing

```
checkedValues[agn] = {};
checkedValues[agn]['pl'].push = $(this).data('kid');
```

To

```
checkedValues[agn] = {pl:[]};/* add property "pl" who's value is empty array*/
 /* now the array exists , can push elements into it*/
checkedValues[agn]['pl'].push($(this).data('kid'));
```

Also note `push()` syntax you are using is incorrect.....should be `push( value )`

Comment: @bfavaretto yup...too early this morning...didn't notice hat...thx

Comment: Have tried as u suggested resulted like this :
         Object { agnName={

                       pl {
                     push=>479
                      }

                  }}

desired O/P is object { agnName => 'pl' => {4,5,6}}

Answer (score 0):

associative arrays are done as objects in Javascript:

```
var data = {
    agnName: {
        pl: [4, 5, 6]
    }
}
```

so you can access data.agnName.pl[0] to return 4 or more dynamically with data['agnName'].pl[0]

Comment: how will it be created dynamically in $.each loop? firstime if array doenst exist it has to create, if exist then it has to push values to particular index...

Answer (score 0):

To create a mulch-dimensional obj. you have to initialize obj and then you can enter value. like below

```
var obj = {}

obj[dynamicval1] = {};
obj[dynamicval1][dynamicval2] = {};
obj[dynamicval1][dynamicval2] = {key1:value1,key2:value2};
```

Hope it works!